# Plotting categorical data with pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with categorical data:

```
     colour  direction
1    red     up
2    blue    up
3    green   down
4    red     left
5    red     right
6    yellow  down
7    blue    down
```

I want to generate some graphs, like pie charts and histograms based on the categories. Is it possible without creating dummy numeric variables? Something like

```
df.plot(kind='hist')
```

Answer (score 265, accepted):

You can simply use `value_counts` on the series:

```
df['colour'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: Suggesting `df["colour"].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')` as common alternative

Comment: Is it possible to specify the order of the x labels?

Comment: Yes, you can specify the order of the x-labels explicitly, e.g. `df['colour'].value_counts()[['green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red']]`

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I make adjustments to this plot. I mean like if I want to change the color for every class or I want to add a legend to it.

Comment: these days, the syntax `df["colour"].value_counts().plot().bar()` is more pandarific syntax - but this saved me some pain! Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

You might find useful [`mosaic`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot.mosaic.html) plot from statsmodels. Which can also give statistical highlighting for the variances.

```
from statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot import mosaic
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 16.0
mosaic(df, ['direction', 'colour']);
```

[image]

But beware of the 0 sized cell - they will cause problems with labels.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31031988/4077912) for details

Comment: Thanks. I keep getting 
ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer on it.

Comment: That's why I referenced [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31031988/4077912). It should help to address this problem.

Answer (score 24):

like this :

```
df.groupby('colour').size().plot(kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 19):

You could also use `countplot` from `seaborn`.  This package builds on `pandas` to create a high level plotting interface. It gives you good styling and correct axis labels for free.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

df = pd.DataFrame({'colour': ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'yellow', 'blue'],
                   'direction': ['up', 'up', 'down', 'left', 'right', 'down', 'down']})
sns.countplot(df['colour'], color='gray')
```

[image]

It also supports coloring the bars in the right color with a little trick

```
sns.countplot(df['colour'],
              palette={color: color for color in df['colour'].unique()})
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. How can i modify the names of the variable e.g i have nearly 10 categories of a variable and when i make this graph the name overlap each other. What can i do to not make this happen? Should i increase the figsize or something?

Answer (score 15):

To plot multiple categorical features as bar charts on the same plot, I would suggest:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "colour": ["red", "blue", "green", "red", "red", "yellow", "blue"],
        "direction": ["up", "up", "down", "left", "right", "down", "down"],
    }
)

categorical_features = ["colour", "direction"]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(categorical_features))
for i, categorical_feature in enumerate(df[categorical_features]):
    df[categorical_feature].value_counts().plot("bar", ax=ax[i]).set_title(categorical_feature)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use `value_counts` with `sort` option set to `False`. This will preserve ordering of the categories

```
df['colour'].value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar(rot=0)
```

[image: link to image]

Answer (score 3):

> #### `Pandas.Series.plot.pie`
>
> https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.pie.html

We can do a little better than that without straying from the built-in functionality.

People love to hate on pie charts, but they have the same benefit as a mosaic/tree; they help keep proportion-to-the-whole interpretable.

```py
kwargs = dict(
    startangle = 90,
    colormap   = 'Pastel2',
    fontsize   = 13,
    explode    = (0.1,0.1,0.1),
    figsize    = (60,5),
    autopct    = '%1.1f%%',
    title      = 'Chemotherapy Stratification'
)

df['treatment_chemo'].value_counts().plot.pie(**kwargs)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using plotly

```
import plotly.express as px
px.bar(df["colour"].value_counts())
```

Answer (score 2):

Roman's answer is very helpful and correct but in latest version you also need to specify kind as the parameter's order can change.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "colour": ["red", "blue", "green", "red", "red", "yellow", "blue"],
    "direction": ["up", "up", "down", "left", "right", "down", "down"],
    }
)

categorical_features = ["colour", "direction"]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(categorical_features))
for i, categorical_feature in enumerate(df[categorical_features]):
    df[categorical_feature].value_counts().plot(kind="bar", ax=ax[i]).set_title(categorical_feature)
fig.show()
```