# Matplotlib.pyplot.hist() very slow

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm plotting about 10,000 items in an array. They are of around 1,000 unique values.

The plotting has been running half an hour now. I made sure rest of the code works.

Is it that slow? This is my first time plotting histograms with pyplot.

Comment: Yes, I would say that is very slow. In reality it depends on how many bins you selected, but i.e. for a 1000 bins I can plot 10 000 random generated values in about a second or two. Python 2, laptop core Intel i5 os Ubuntu 14.04. Show some code, it'll make things easier.

Comment: Actually I solved it by just reducing number of bins. Thanks though.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct column data type? I was using strings instead of integers and that was a sheer error on my part.

Answer (score 27):

To plot histograms using matplotlib quickly you need to pass the `histtype='step'` argument to `pyplot.hist`. For example:

```
plt.hist(np.random.exponential(size=1000000,bins=10000))
plt.show()
```

takes ~15 seconds to draw and roughly 5-10 seconds to update when you pan or zoom.

In contrast, plotting with `histtype='step'`:

```
plt.hist(np.random.exponential(size=1000000),bins=10000,histtype='step')
plt.show()
```

plots almost immediately and can be panned and zoomed with no delay.

Comment: This is much faster as you say (I'm seeing the same times as you).  But the graphs look very different with histtype='step'.

Comment: @dementedhedgehog yes, they do. I guess it depends on which discipline you are in. In high energy physics the step style is the norm. I opened an issue on the matplotlib page to discuss the issue here a while ago: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7121.

Answer (score 16):

It will be instant to plot the histogram after flattening the numpy array. Try the below demo code:

```
import numpy as np

array2d = np.random.random_sample((512,512))*100
plt.hist(array2d.flatten())
plt.hist(array2d.flatten(), bins=1000)
```

Comment: Was having this same issue, this solution worked like a charm.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Handled 100k values instantly as opposed to it not returning otherwise. If plotting multiple histograms, `array2d.flatten()` does cause the histograms to be plotted as one. Resolution is to add each column separately.

Comment: This should the accepted answer. Far, far superior to the ones more upvoted

Comment: This is fantastic! But I wonder why flattening the array would have such a huge improvement in executing time like that?

Answer (score 7):

Importing [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) somewhere in the code may cause [pyplot.hist](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) to take a really long time.

If the problem is seaborn, it can be solved by resetting the matplotlib settings:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.reset_orig()
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, the problem is that the data type of `pd.Series`, say S, is `'object'` rather than `'float64'`. After I use `S = np.float64(S)`, then `plt.hist(S)` is very quick.

Comment: The correct way to change the type of a `pandas.Series` is with `.astype()`: `S.astype('float64')`

Answer (score 2):

Since several answers already mention the issue of slowness with `pandas.hist()`, note that it may be due to dealing with non-numerical data.  An issue easily solved by using `value_counts()` :

```
df['colour'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

[credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31029857/812102)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem using Pandas `.hist()` method. For me the solution was:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['your_data']).hist()
```

Which worked instantly.

Answer (score 0):

For me it took calling `figure.canvas.draw()` after the call to hist to update immediately, i.e. hist was actually fast (discovered that after timing it), but there was a delay of a few seconds before figure was updated. I was calling hist inside a matplotlib callback in a jupyter lab cell (qt5 backend).

Answer (score 0):

Anyone running into the issue I had - (which is totally my bad :)  )

If you're dealing with numbers, make sure when reading from CSV that your datatype is int/float, and not string.

```
values_arr = .... .flatten().astype('float')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with pandas, make sure the data you passed in plt.hist() is a 1-d series rather than a dataframe. This helped me out.