# Retaining category order when charting/plotting ordered categorical Series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Consider the following categorical `pd.Series`:

```
In [37]: df = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(['good', 'good', 'ok', 'bad', 'bad', 'awful', 'awful'], categories=['bad', 'ok', 'good', 'awful'], ordered=True))

In [38]: df
Out[38]:
0     good
1     good
2       ok
3      bad
4      bad
5    awful
6    awful
dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [bad < ok < good < awful]
```

I want to draw a pie or bar chart of these. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31029857/2071807), plotting categorical `Series` requires me to plot the `value_counts`, but this does not retain the categorical ordering:

```
df.value_counts().plot.bar()
```

How can I plot an ordered categorical variable and retain the ordering?
[image: Bar chart]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add parameter `sort=False` in [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
print df.value_counts()
awful    2
good     2
bad      2
ok       1
dtype: int64

print df.value_counts(sort=False)
bad      2
ok       1
good     2
awful    2
dtype: int64

print df.value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]

Or add [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html):

```
print df.value_counts().sort_index()
bad      2
ok       1
good     2
awful    2
dtype: int64

print df.value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar()
```

Comment: Second solution should probably be the first.

Comment: @Alexander - Thank you, solutions are swapped.