# Displaying distribution of categorical variables in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

A great feature supported by Pandas is the `data.hist()`. The `hist` function allows me to visualize the distribution of numerical values. However, that being said: it only allows me to view the distribution for numerical variables.

If I wanted to view the distribution of categorical variables, I'd need to run `select_dtypes` in a for loop as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for col in tips.select_dtypes(include=["category"]):
    tips[col].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
    plt.show()
```

Is there an easier (more Pythonic) way to view the distribution of categorical variables.

Comment: Take a look at https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/categorical.html

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I am familiar with Seaborn - but I'd love to stick with the pandas ecosystem.

Comment: @Phil it would probably help if you explained *why* "absolutely not". Assuming that you meant that the duplicate doesn't apply. The accepted answer seems to do the same thing you're doing in the loop.

Comment: I have a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54266570/5084355