# Histogram of IP addresses (Panda Series)

Tags: python, pandas, ip-address, data-mining, valueerror

I wish to plot a histogram to check frequency of occurrence of IP addresses used for data mining.

My snippet:-

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p1 = r'small_set.csv'
d = pd.read_csv(p1, engine='python')
source_ip = d['Source IP']
source_ip.hist()
```

My 'source_ip' is a panda series type variable, that looks as follows:-

```
>>> source_ip
0          8.0.69.0
1          8.0.69.0
2          8.0.69.0
3          8.0.69.0
4          8.0.69.0
5          8.0.69.0
          ...      
69    192.168.10.17
70    192.168.10.17
71    192.168.10.17
72    192.168.10.17
73    192.168.10.17
74    192.168.10.17
Name: Source IP, Length: 74, dtype: object
```

However at line `source_ip.hist()`, I get the following error:-

```
File "/home/developer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/histograms.py", line 253, in _get_outer_edges
    "supplied range of [{}, {}] is not finite".format(first_edge, last_edge))
ValueError: supplied range of [inf, 8.0.69.0] is not finite
```

As a work-around, I found the count of the frequencies using `value_counts()` as follows:-

```
s = d['Source IP'].value_counts()
>>> s
8.0.69.0         28
192.168.10.17    26
192.168.10.12    25
192.168.10.19    12
192.168.10.50     8
Name: Source IP, dtype: int64
```

But it's still not the same. How do I get rid of that Value Error and display a legit histogram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a qualitative histogram

```
df['Source IP'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

[Other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029560/plotting-categorical-data-with-pandas-and-matplotlib)