# How to plot this dataframe columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to plot the columns of the DataFrame which contains variable `Edition` in `x-axis` and `Performances` in `y-axis`.

[image]

I tried this code:

```
df.plot(x='Edition',y='Performances')
```

But it gives an error:

```
no numeric data to plot.
```

Can someone please suggest how I could do this?

Comment: I don't think pandas can plot categorical values on the y axis. You can use matplotlib, `plt.plot(df["Edition"].values, df["Performances"].values)`.

Comment: This is a very similar question to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31029560/1930737

Comment: Thanks a lot.!! It worked.