# Is there a graph to plot non numeric data (categorical data) on both axes in Jupyter Notebook(Python)?

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis

I am trying to plot a graph for the data set which has only categorical data(no numeric data) so what library I can use to plot the graph for categorical data on both axes.  I have used seaborn.stripplot() but it also requires one numeric data for an axis.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029560/plotting-categorical-data-with-pandas-and-matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it - but could you create a Enum with the Categorical data for 1 of the axis's. Obviously it can not be dynamic values.

You may be able get that to work.

Just a thought however - I HAVE NOT tried this.